# shell script: Read a particular string from file

Tags: shell, sh

here is the file content:

```
CPU revision    : 0
Hardware        : nomen TOS 9900 (Flattened Device Tree)
Revision        : nomen TOS 8800 (Flattened Device Tree)
Serial          : 0000
```

using Linux shell script, I need to read this file and get only 9900 (from Hardware: line) into a string, what is the best way? thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your work, and we'll help you fix the bugs.  And in your sample input, *what are the other possible values of the "Hardware" line?*

Answer (score 1):

Given the extent of the information you've provided, this is a really easy task using a variety of tools.

```
$ awk '$1=="Hardware"{print $5}' sample.txt
```

Awk looks for a match on an expression, then separates the line into fields delimited by whitespace.  `$1` is the first word, `$5` is the fifth "word".

```
$ sed -ne '/^Hardware/s/[^0-9]//gp' sample.txt
```

The sed command can also execute commands on lines that match specific regexes.  In this case, for "Hardware" lines, we're replacing every non-numeric character with null, which obviously leaves the number.  This separates by type rather than by field.  (You didn't state what you were trying to achieve.)

And finally:

```
$ readarray -t stuff < sample.txt
$ for line in "${stuff[@]}"; do this=($line); test "${this[0]}" = "Hardware" && echo "${this[4]}"; done
```

Without using any external tools, this finds the line using bash alone.  Note that this kind of array reference doesn't work in older Bourne-style shells.  But if you're in Linux or OSX, your shell is likely bash by default.

And if you're wondering about `"${this[4]}"`, the "4" is because bash arrays are numbered from zero, whereas awk lines are word-split starting at `$1`.

We could do this in non-bash shell as well, but it would be a lot more work, and probably not a one-liner.